# Setup of JMS message listener fails whenever there is a upgrade to azure servicebus

Tags: azureservicebus, spring-jms, azure-servicebus-queues

I get a warning log when servicebus does an upgrade to their system.

`Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue-name' - trying to recover. Cause: Local transactions cannot span multiple top-level entities such as queue or topic`

this is weird because messages are still sent and received from the queue. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

The setup of the jmslistener is also pretty standard

```
  @JmsListener(destination = "queue-name", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
  public void listenQueueName(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code to set up a Spring JMS message listener using the **`@JmsListener`** annotation and can able to receive messages from queue.

**Code:**

**MyJmsListener.java** :

```java
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyJmsListener {

 @JmsListener(destination = "kamqueue", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
 public void listenQueueName(String message) {

     System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
     
 }
}
```

**MyJmsListenerApplication.java** :

```java
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyJmsListenerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MyJmsListenerApplication.class, args);
        
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("kamqueue", "Hello, JMS Listener!");
        
        context.close();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully and received the message of the queue as below,

[image]

Reference: Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/cloud-scale-messaging-with-jms-service-bus/5-receive-messages-from-service-bus) to send messages to Service bus Queue with Jms Listener.